# Capybara: Select an option by value not text

Tags: ruby, capybara

For the HTML

```html
<select id="date">
  <option value="20120904">Tue 4 Sep 2012</option>
  <option value="20120905">Wed 5 Sep 2012</option>
  <option value="20120906">Thu 6 Sep 2012</option>
</select>
```

I have the following Capybara Ruby code:

```ruby
select "20120905", :from => "date"
```

But this errors with:

```
cannot select option, no option with text '20120905' in select box 'date' (Capybara::ElementNotFound)
```

However, if I do

```ruby
select "Wed 5 Sep 2012", :from => "date"
```

It's ok.

Is it possible to select an option in Capybara by *Value* not *Text*?

Thanks

Answer (score 77, accepted):

This will work to select an option by value:

```
find("option[value='20120905']").click
```

To maintain the scope of the selector you could wrap it in a within block as such:

```
within '#date' do
  find("option[value='20120905']").click
end
```

Comment: After switching from Selenium to Poltergeist found that this method do not work. Therefore replaced by find('#select_id').find('option[value="1"]').select_option Sorry for bad English.

Comment: @woto All this options do not work for me. Basically the option is found without problems. I have checked the result and it finds the correct option, but it does not click or select it. I think it needs to first open the select before selecting the option.

Answer (score 43):

With Poltergeist as driver I can't click on an option like suggested in some of the other options above, instead you can do the following:

`page.find_by_id('date').find("option[value='20120905']").select_option`

Comment: Super useful. I created a helper method in spec/support/capybara.rb: def select_option params
  id = params[:id]
  value = params[:value]
  page.find_by_id(id).find("option[value='#{value}']").select_option
end

Comment: `click` cause for me `The element you are trying to interact with is either not part of the DOM, or is not currently visible on the page` but `select_option` works for me just fine. Thanks!

Comment: This is the answer for capybara-webkit as well.

Answer (score 21):

I wrote a helper method:

```
def select_by_value(id, value)
  option_xpath = "//*[@id='#{id}']/option[@value='#{value}']"
  option = find(:xpath, option_xpath).text
  select(option, :from => id)
end
```

Save in a .rb file in *spec/support/*

Example use:

```
before do
  select_by_value 'some_field_id', 'value'
  click_button 'Submit'
end
```

Comment: Intention-revealing name, nice implementation. Thanks.

Comment: This (still) seems to be the only version that works without javascript and is somewhat independent of the driver ...

Answer (score 4):

You can also achieve it by doing the following:

```
find_by_id('date').find("option[value='20120905']").click
```

Answer (score 3):

That helper method is pretty clever. I would change it just a little bit:

```
def select_by_value(id, value)

  option_xpath = "//*[@id='#{id}']/option[@value='#{value}']"

  find(:xpath, option_xpath).click

end
```

or just:

```
find(:xpath, "//select[@id='date']/option[@value='20120904']").click
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I have a few options with same text, that's the reason why I need select by value. Combining a few answers together I've found the best solution for me:

```
def select_by_value(id, value)
  option_xpath = "//*[@id='#{id}']/option[@value='#{value}']"
  find(:xpath, option_xpath).select_option
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Click using find_field works fine:

```
find_field("date").find("option[value='20120905']").click
```

Comment: It gave me error. Unable to find css "option[value='20120905']"

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [capybara-ui](https://github.com/mojotech/capybara-ui) which will look first to match the text, then to match the value.

```
# define your form widget, in this case in a role
class UserRole < Capybara::UI::Role
  form :my_form do
    select :my_select, 'my_select'
  end
end

# then just submit your form params via #submit
role = UserRole.new

role.submit :my_form, my_select: '20120905'
```

See more about capybara-ui forms [here](https://github.com/mojotech/capybara-ui/blob/master/docs/widgets.md#forms).

Answer (score 0):

In case of not visible field, try this

```
find("#date", visible: false).find("option[value='20120905']").click
```

Or with scope as:

```
within '#date', visible: false do
    find("option[value='20120905']").click
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the value.

`find(selector).set(value)`