# How do I select an element from the grouped selection by its value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

The problem I'm having (and I've tried all the solutions on the interwebs) is how to select an element from a grouped select with capybara.

Here's the dropdown:

```
<%= f.grouped_collection_select(:subcategory_id, Category.order(:name), :subcategories, :name, :id, :name, {}, { :class=> "form-control" }) %>
```

Here's one of the ways I've tried to select it.

```
select("Ortodoncista", from: 'provider[subcategory_id]')
```

The error

```
Unable to find option "Ortodoncista" (Capybara::ElementNotFound)
```

Comment: I recommend you use the `save_and_open_page` method and include the source code of the page to have a better understanding.

Comment: That's a great idea. I'll do that next time :)

Comment: @MauricioMoraes, I only marked your suggested edit as useful because of the nice improved title. You left lots of noise behind, check my edit.

Comment: That's way better! Just for freddyrangel to know, your question is a good one, but it wasn't very direct and had repeated information. Thanks brasofilo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer worked for me [Capybara: Select an option by value not text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265174/select-an-option-by-value-not-text-in-capybara/15821255#15821255) by @d_rail

You create a helper first. I put this helper in `spec/support/utilities.rb`

```
def select_by_value(id, value)
  option_xpath = "//*[@id='#{id}']/option[@value='#{value}']"
  option = find(:xpath, option_xpath).text
  select(option, :from => id)
end
```

Then to use it:

```
select_by_value "select_id", "select_option"
```

In my case, the select tag has the id `user_category` and the option I wanted to select was `Musician`. So my example was

```
select_by_value "user_category", "Musician"
```

Answer (score 1):

As I am more familiar with CSS selection, I would use:

This to find option element by its value, that correspond to the result of the **option_key_method** (:id), on a child of your *collection* (Categories):

```
 page.find('select#your-selectbox-id option[value="your-value"]')
```

This will return the desired capybara element found by ***your-value*** instead of searching by the text of the option. Then you can do whatever you want. for example: ***.text***, or ***.click***.

Or (just to remember) like this, if you want to select a given option from your selecbox with capybara:

```
select 'Option Label', :from => 'Selectbox Label Text'
```

wich, in your case would be the result of the **option_value_method** (:name) on a child of your *collection* (Categories).

Obs: [reference for grouped selection](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/grouped_collection_select)