# Capybara select_option is found, but not selected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I am trying with Capybara to use the [Select Method](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/node/actions.rb#L183). I tried all the solutions included, especially those from this [Stackoverflow Discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265174/capybara-select-an-option-by-value-not-text).

I have the following select done with the **country_select** gem. This is the html.erb code from the form:

```
<%= f.country_select(:country, {include_blank: 'Select a country', selected: "Select a country"}, {class: 'form-control', :id => "country_select"}) %>
```

The html from the browser looks like this:

```
<select class="form-control" id="country_select" name="user[country]"><option value="">Select a country</option>
    <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="AX">Åland Islands</option>
    <option value="AL">Albania</option>
    other staff...
```

When I debug the select method from the Capybara GEM [file actions.rb row 183](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/node/actions.rb#L183) (where I set a breakpoint), the output is correct.

```
  def select(value, options={})
    binding.pry
    if options.has_key?(:from)
      from = options.delete(:from)
      find(:select, from, options).find(:option, value, options).select_option
    else
      find(:option, value, options).select_option
    end
  end
```

So the line:

```
find(:select, from, options).find(:option, value, options)
```

returns

```
=> #<Capybara::Node::Element tag="option" path="/html/body/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/form/div[4]/select/option[2]">
```

Which is the correct select option. As you can see the `option[2]` is Afganistan, but it looks like `.select_option` does not work.

I think Capybara is not opening the select box before selecting the field.
I have  capybara (2.13.0) and rails 5.0.2

Thanks a lot
Fabrizio Bertoglio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks.

I solved the problem. Sorry, it is a stupid solution.

I forgot in my Application Controller to include:

```
before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
```

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters