# Capybara::ElementNotFound for grouped_select's simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara, simple-form

I used `grouped_select` input to group nested associations. (see images below)
It looks like Capybara can't find this kind of input.

```
Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find option "Ryan, Reynolds and Effertz" within #<Capybara::Node::Element tag="select"
```

These are my specs

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :project_type do
    organization

    name { FFaker::Company.unique.name }
  end
end
```

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :project_stage do
    project_type

    name { FFaker::Company.unique.name }
  end
end
```

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :project do
    user
    stage factory: :project_stage

    name { FFaker::Company.unique.name }
    note { FFaker::Lorem.phrase }
    start_date { Date.new(2022, 01, 01) }
    end_date { Date.new(2022, 12, 19) }
    budget { 10000 }
  end
end
```

```
  test "should create project" do
    login_as @user
    visit projects_url
    find(:css, ".project-application .new-item").click

    fill_in "project_name", with: @project.name
    fill_in "project_budget", with: @project.budget
    fill_in "project_start_date", with: @project.start_date
    fill_in "project_end_date", with: @project.end_date
    fill_in "project_note", with: @project.note
    select(@project.stage.name, from: "Stade ")
    # fill_in "project_project_stage_id", with: @project.project_stage_id
    find(:css, ".hubflo-modal .save-item").click

    assert_text(:all, "Projet créé")
    find(:css, ".project-application .back-to-index").click
  end
```

[image: form]
[image: inspect element]

Comment: Try out this code without a space at the end of the label. Also, make sure the label itself does not have a space at end in the content. Instead, use CSS padding for moving star further from the label text.

Comment: Are you sure the option (Ryan, Reynolds and Effertz) you're trying to select is in the `select` tag you're specifying, it's not in the picture.  Show the actual html of the options in the select from your test.

Comment: You are both right. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find option "Ryan, Reynolds and Effertz" within #<Capybara::Node::Element tag="select"`

Capybara is finding the select tag correctly, it's just not finding that option in the list. I think you're right that it's struggling with the grouping.

Try [selecting an option by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265174/capybara-select-an-option-by-value-not-text/15821255#15821255) instead of the text.

But, @Thomas Walpole makes a good point.

I tend to believe Capybara is telling the truth. Which means:

`@project.stage.name` is not an option in the list.

This could be because the controller or view is not creating the select correctly.

It could also be that your test is not saving `@project.stage` before the controller or view calls for the collection of stages.

Try this:

```rb
test "should create project" do
  login_as @user
  visit projects_url
  find(:css, ".project-application .new-item").click

  # debugger to manually verify that @project.stage.name is in the select list
  save_and_open_page

  # fill_in "project_name", with: @project.name
  # fill_in "project_budget", with: @project.budget
  # fill_in "project_start_date", with: @project.start_date
  # fill_in "project_end_date", with: @project.end_date
  # fill_in "project_note", with: @project.note
  # select(@project.stage.name, from: "Stade ")
  # fill_in "project_project_stage_id", with: @project.project_stage_id
  # find(:css, ".hubflo-modal .save-item").click

  # assert_text(:all, "Projet créé")
  # find(:css, ".project-application .back-to-index").click
end
```

Comment: Capybara has no issues with standard `optgroup` grouping of options in a select.  It's more likely the option being looked for doesn't actually exist in the select - which would make sense if the @project instance being built to use for filling in the data wasn't built with an existing stage...

Comment: Yes `"Ryan, Reynolds and Effertz" ` was not on the list.
Thanks!